# find the match keyword and return some text in front of matched keyword till first occurrence of comma

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains 3 columns

df =

```
|  id    |            product_details                               | taxo |
   100        [Sales Package=6 Pair slipper,
               Strap Material=Rubber, qty=1,
               categoryPath=Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops,          1
               codAvailable=true, detailedSpecs=Multicolor Color, 
               None Character Type Slippers For Men
               Sole Material Rubber]

    200        [Brand Fit=Regular, Fabric=Cotton Polyester Blend,
               Fabric Care=Hand wash, Fit=Regular, Ideal For=Mens, 
               Neck Type=Round Neck, Pack of=1, Pattern=Graphic Print,   2 
               Reversible=No, Sales Package=1 T-Shirt, Size=M, 
               Sleeve=Half Sleeve, Sleeve Type=Wide, 
               Suitable For=Western Wear, 
               categoryPath=Apparels>Men>Polos & T-Shirts, 
               codAvailable=true, detailedSpecs=Fabric Cotton 
               Polyester Blen  Regular Fit Round Neck T-shirt  
               Pattern Graphic Print  Sleeve Type Wide Half Sleeve, 
               discountPercentage=0]
```

i want to find keyword categoryPath in product_details column of dataframe and return some text in front of it, till first occurrence of comma and write it into new dataframe (df_new)

i have over 8 million rows in my dataframe.

Expected output: df_new

```
| id  |         category_path                 |
  100    Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops

  200    Apparels>Men>Polos & T-Shirts
```

Comment: Can you explain why it's important to use a regular expression?  And can you show what code you've tried so far to accomplish this?

Comment: well i am new to python so i saw many people suggest to use regex (although it is not compulsory to use regex only)

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest removing the requirement that an answer uses regex (though someone may well post a regex answer).  Also, I'd suggest reading about how to ask you question in [a way that's easier for people to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sure I will check that post, meanwhile if you have any solution then please forward it so I can check. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are those lists of strings? or one big string that has brackets on the ends?

Comment: It is list of list. Thank you sir!

Comment: List of lists, how?  Split by semicolon then comma?  Other way around?  You're not being very forthcoming with details that are important to answering your question.

Comment: It is list of list separated by comma, it is my mistake that I put semi colon in data I will correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this regex: `categoryPath=[\w>\s&]+`

you get `Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops`

out of `Sales Package=6 Pair slipper, Strap Material=Rubber, qty=1, categoryPath=Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops, codAvailable=true, detailedSpecs=Multicolor Color; None Character; Type: Slippers; For Men; Sole Material: Rubber`

I guess that's what you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer  I will check your solution and will update you.

Comment: sorry for the interruption but the regex there gives you `categoryPath=Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops` so you have to use brackets to group `Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops` use this regex `categoryPath=([\w>\s&]+)` and then use group to get `Footwear>Men>Slippers & Flip Flops`